# Как заполнить массив значениями, каждое из которых больше предыдущего на 3, с помощью цикла

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Нужно создать пустой массив из 10 целых чисел и с помощью цикла заполнить его значениями, каждое из которых будет на 3 больше предыдущего (начиная с 1), то есть получить `[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28]`.

Написал такой код:

```
public class massiv {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i] + 3; //вот тут туплю - не пойму как решить
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Как правильно заполнить массив?

Comment: `array[i] = i*3 + 1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цикл со второго элемента массива.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[10];
    array[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i - 1] + 3;//вот тут туплю - не пойму как решить
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

До начала цикла мы присваиваем значение элементу [0]. Затем начинаем цикл с элемента [1]. На каждом шаге итерации мы используем предыдущий элемент для добавления к нему 3 и присвоения следующему элементу.

Так цикл работает:

array[1] = array[0] + 3. Получаем array[1] = 4.

Потом array[2] = array[1]+3. Получаем array[2] = 4+3 = 7, ну и т.д.

Comment: объясни автору  почему array[i-1]

Comment: так вроде объяснили ниже в каментах. ОК, попытка №2 ))  До начала цикла мы присваиваем значение элементу [0]. Затем начинаем цикл с элемента [1]. на каждом шаге итерации мы используем предыдущий элемент для добавления к нему 3 и присвоения следующему элементу. Так работает: array[1] = array[0] + 3. Получаем array[1] = 4. Потом array[2] = array[1]+3. Получаем array[2] = 4+3 = 7, ну и т.д.

Comment: Так-то у нас тут заведено `объясни` понимать как `дополни ответ`. Полезная инфа не должна пылиться в комментариях.

Comment: Лады, сейчас закину туда

Answer (score 3):

Так как заданную рекурсивную функцию

```
F(0) = 1;
F(n) = F(n - 1) + 3;
```

Можно заменить на нерекурсивную:

```
F(n) = n * 3 + 1;
```

То можно сделать чуть короче с привязкой значения к номеру итерации (`i`):

```
int[] array = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = i * 3 + 1;
}
```

А в случае использования Java 8:

```
int[] array = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(e -> e * 3 + 1).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[10];
    int value = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = value;
        value += 3;
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array[i] = array[i]+3;`//вот тут туплю - не пойму как решить

да, именно тут загвоздка, Вы, вероятно, хотите увеличить значение предыдущего элемента на 3. Для этого можно сделать так:

```
 array[i] = array[i-1]+3;
```

Однако, в этом случае нужно начать цикл не с нулевого элемента array[0], а с первого array[1], потому как элемента `array[i-1]` (т.е. `array[0-1]`) не существует

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
> ```

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
```

> ```
> array[i] = array[i] + 3;
> ```

```
array[i] = array[i-1] + 3;
```

Comment: Под каким углом нужно смотреть на это?

Comment: @Regent, читаешь строчку в цитате, читаешь строчку вне цитаты, находишь изменения. Повторяешь для второй цитаты. Понимаешь и идёшь править код :)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/145692)

Comment: @vp_arth, почему не является?

Comment: Хотя этот код может быть решением проблемы, ответ должен содержать информацию о том, почему он решает проблему. К тому же, на тот момент когда был написан этот ответ уже присутствовали более развернутые аналогичные ответы.

Comment: @vp_arth, а иногда хочется почитать короткий :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i= i + 3) {
```

Comment: Да ну? И чисел получится, сколько нужно?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]